# Web services response in client language - how to?

Tags: java, web-services, internationalization

I am developing a SOAP web service in Java using metro.
I want to deliver the response in in the client language.
My idea is to return all the string fields translates. This is not the main purpose for the web service, but is a needed convenience.

The [ResourceBundle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) is a java class that handles the loading of the correct set of strings according the client Location.
Is this class the best approacher?

And the real question: in a WS environment how to know the client location?

EDIT:
I like @Volker idea, let decide what language will be used.

How to send the intentions to the service?

- Header parameter?
- Method (body) parameter?
- Any other option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, I would say, if possible, let the client explicitly tell you what language he wants and deliver it according to his needs.

This may be an additional web method "getSupportedLanguages" which delivers a list of enUS, deDE or whatever and your other methods may accept those languages and deliver the correct response. Or deliver all language versions and let the client sort it out. But this may be a bit network overkill depending on the number of supported locales...

In my opinion, WebServices should "stand on their own", the clients should be thin and not require lots of information to process the content. Imagine a C#-client, who may not be able to work with your Ressources or whatever. Or a new client without ressources not being able to work with your data...

Additionally, it could be different to really get the clients locale - a non-english person may use an english system or may be in an english country, but would like to see data in his native language. But if you really need to do this, I'm not aware of anything to enable this.

Answer (score 2):

Is the translation the main purpose of your service or is it just seen as a convenience to the user?

For the latter case I would kind of go about the problem the other way round:

Is it, in your application design, in any way possible to send language-neutral messages (like `service.fail` or something like that) to the client, and have the client translate them due to a local resource bundle? This would allow independent users of your service allow to transform your answer into anything they want, including translation using ResourceBundle. It is, in my eyes the job of the client interface to show the appropriate message, not the job of your service.

Of course, the downside of this is that you won't have your resource bundles all in one place anymore.

As to the other side of your question: ResourceBundle is the way to go, it has been specifically designed for the task.

Also: I am not aware of any way for a web-service to know anything about it's clients other directly intercepting the Http-Request and reading it's fields, specifically `Accept-Language`. These fields encode languages like `en-US`.

Comment: Edited the question; the translations is secondary, but needed. The ws returns an object with a set of fields, and those who are strings need to e translated.